Is this the correct genus for a (2n)-gon? (Answer part (b))
This question is from a publicly available practice qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. I did the first part of this question here. For convenience, I've integrated my answer from the first part into this post, so all the information needed is on this page.
For $n \ge 2$, let $X_n$ be the space obtained from a regular $(2n)$-gon by identifying the opposite sides with parallel orientations. For example, $X_3$ is

The above description produces a cell decomposition of $X_n$
The associated cellular chain complex for this shape is
$$  \; 0 \rightarrow \mathbb Z \xrightarrow{d_2} \mathbb Z^n \xrightarrow{d_1} \mathbb Z^{\zeta} \rightarrow 0 \;$$
Where
$$ \zeta = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } n \text{ is even} \\ 2 &\text{if } n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$
(b): Show that $X_n$ is a surface, and find its genus.

Answer part (b):
The space can be triangulated and we are only quotienting two edges at a time. As a result it will meet the conditions of being a surface. Furthermore, since all edges are identified, this gives us a closed surface.
Then the Euler characteristic for a closed surface of genus $g$ is given as
$$ \chi = \zeta - n + 1 = 2 - 2g$$
re-arranging, we obtain the genus of the surface as
$$  g = {n + 1 - \zeta \over 2} $$
which simplifies to
$$ \boxed{ g = \begin{cases} (n / 2)  && \text{if } n \text{ is even} \\ (n - 1) / 2  &&  \text{if } n \text{ is odd}\end{cases} }$$

Is this correct?
More specifically, is my formula for using the Euler characteristic for a closed surface the correct choice for computing the genus? Is the result itself correct?
The only recommended textbook for this practice is Hatcher's algebraic topology, so I don't think the proof that $X_n$ is a surface needs to go down to the atomic level. Hatcher mentions that you have a surface if you only quotient two edges at a time. If my statement is true then I think it's a sufficient level of detail for the context of this question and the expected level of education.

At a quick glance, you're asking for a solution-verification, so I've added that tag (and removed the prior one). Per the tag, can you "identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so".

@CalvinLin Alright,
I just emphasized that I want to make sure using the Euler characteristic is the right choice and gives the right result.
You are also asked to show that $X_n$ is a surface. The recommended textbook to study for this exam is only Hatcher's book. As a result, I used a general argument from triangulating the surface and only doing two quotients at a time (which Hatcher says gives a surface). So long as that statement is true, I think that's OK for the context of this question, and what would be expected out of a student.

There are other textbooks for introductory algebraic topology if you're looking for one, though they don't really have any significant difference in content (as opposed to presentation), and I personally think Hatcher is the best of them.

As for the solution: I'm not sure what definition of "surface" you're using (say, whether you're working in the category of topological manifolds, CW-complexes, etc.), but the basic idea is right: You're starting with a compact 2-manifold or 2-dimensional complex, and the quotient maps give you an appropriate neighborhood on what used to be the boundary. (You can mention that you can take the triangulation to include each of the boundary pieces, if that's the sort of thing they're looking for). For the latter part...

... they're probably checking whether you know that the Euler characteristic of a complex is invariant under passing to homology (modulo some finiteness assumptions that are clearly satisfied here). That looks like what you're doing here, but it might help to be explicit if it's for a qualifying exam.
